# How to get the status of an URL?

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply, qnetworkrequest

I am using Qt and what I should do is given a `QString` containing my URL, before opening the page, I want to know if this is reachable.

I read the documentation of `QNetworkReply` and I saw that there are different codes for the different types of error (eg: the remote content was not found at the server -> code 203).

**The question is:** starting from my `QString`, how can I get those code values?

Comment: offtopic bro but "resource not found" should be 404

Comment: In Qt documentation at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html , in the section enum QNetworkReply::NetworkError , it says that the corresponding code for the status 404 is 203.

Comment: It is not something you could know in advance, I think, but a trial and error. Make the request, check for errors, get the error code. That should be it.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html

Comment: I have already read this documentation but I am not able to understand how to use the different functions to get what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to know if this is reachable, before opening the page?**

It is not something you could know in advance, but a trial and error:

1. Make the request
2. Check for errors
3. Get the error code

**How can I do this?**

Let's take the example from the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details):

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QNetworkRequest request;

request.setUrl(QUrl("http://put.your-url.here"));

QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);

connect(reply, &QIODevice::readyRead, this, &MyClass::slotReadyRead);
connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::errorOccurred,
        this, &MyClass::slotError);
connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::sslErrors,
        this, &MyClass::slotSslErrors);
```

Now in the implementation of `MyClass::slotError`, write:

```
qDebug() << static_cast<QNetworkReply *>(sender())->error();
```

This should print the error code, if any.